# LAN settings don't save ("managed by your system administrator")

Tags: windows-7, proxy, internet-connection

I'm using WiFi connections or a 3G modem to connect to the Internet, but sometimes the connections break and the LAN settings change to use a proxy server. I have never set a proxy server, and I do not want one.

I set it to *Automatically detect settings*:

[image]

But they somehow get changed back to using a proxy server, without my permission:

[image]

Notice the "some settings are managed by your system administrator" banner.
Here are the advanced settings :
where i have reset and restore them all :

[image: Advanced settings that i set to default]

I have tried rebooting, and other solutions on the Internet:

1. I have deleted `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU` to leave only the "default" entry.
2. I have tried [other solutions](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/unable-to-change-windows-update-settings-some/2aafdc92-fb2e-4347-948d-ca71f87107a4?auth=1) from Microsoft forums

How can I keep my network settings as they should be?

**UPDATE 1**  Here is a screenshot when clicking on advanced :
[image: Advanced settings]

Comment: @DanielB i have added a capture but i have also restore and reset those settings , ans the problem still persist

Comment: Hm, somehow my comment disappeared. Whatever. That wasn’t what I’m referring to. On the proxy settings dialog (“Local Area Network (LAN) Settings”), click the “Advanced” button when the “Use a proxy server for your LAN” checkbox is checked.

Comment: @DanielB yes ok and after that what i should do ?

Comment: Provide a screenshot. :D

Comment: @DanielB ok i have added one but i have changed to automatically detect settings when i have boot up my laptop so they can be different ... but the settings as usual will switch back to proxy mode ... then i will verify if the settings stayed the same

Comment: You probably have some adware or malware on your PC. Check with [TCPView](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/tcpview.aspx) to find out what’s listening on port 8080.

Comment: @DanielB i checked it but there is no port 8080 so no process is listening to it

Comment: Any other usefull hints ?

Comment: The problem seems to be solved after performing some windows updates but i don't know if it will work for you guys

Answer (score 1):

As you chose 'Automatically Detect Settings', it does just that, and the dedicated connection point in the LAN has a script ready that will run. As soon as you save, *that script probably changes the setting to something different* - in your case to 'use a proxy server'.

If you choose none of the check boxes, it will not ask for that script or execute it (but then your LAN might not work...)

I have the same issue whenever I connect from outside the company network, because the company network sets the setting (stupidly) to use a specific script (instead of leaving it on automatic), and the server this script is located on is not reachable from outside the company network. So I have to remove that setting *manually* every time I want to connect from outside.

Comment: I don’t see any relation to the question...? His question is about the settings reverting after saving.

Comment: I marked the part in italics.

Comment: That’s simply not true. The PAC script is run every time, because it can direct you to a new proxy on each connection. It can do more than the static options.

Comment: @Aganju it must be something we can do !!! this issue really disturb me